# Return Only Specific Values From Ajax JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having trouble with filtering the returned data from an Ajax JSON call. Right now, it returns:

```
{"results":[{"text":"RoboChat: What is it like to feel?","username":"RoboChat","createdAt":"2014-06-04T20:01:15.268Z","updatedAt":"2014-06-04T20:01:15.268Z","objectId":"wG2cs1OnVY"},
```

I'm trying to get it to return only the "text" object, like this:

```
"RoboChat:What is it like to feel?"
```

Here is my code:

```
function fetch () {
  $.ajax({
          url:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          type : 'GET',
          dataType : 'JSON',
          data : JSON.stringify({
          }),
          success:function(data) {
       $('.messages').append("<li>" + (JSON.stringify(data)) + "</li>") 
      }
  });
};
```

I've tried passing a filter to JSON.stringify, but with no success, I'm not even sure if that's the way to approach filtering the data. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really change what a request returns, but you can of course use the resulting value in any way you want. Since the response contains multiple objects with `text` properties, you have to iterate them and extract the text:

```
success: function(data) {
    var results = data.results;

    results.forEach(function (result) {
        $('.messages').append("<li>" + result.text + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Comment: *You can't really change what a request returns* ... and why is that?

Comment: I tried this, but it returns this error at line 2 of the answer: (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o).

Comment: @user3705098 You don't need to parse the response, jQuery parses it for you, remove the `JSON.parse` and it should work.

Comment: Yup! Removing JSON.parse solved the error, it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The returned JSON has a `results` property which is an array, you can iterate through the array and read the `text` property of each element:

```
$.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
     console.log(element.text);
});
```

For creating a `li` element for each array's element, you can use the `$.map` utility function:

```
var li = $.map(data.results, function(element) {
    return '<li>' + element.text + '</li>';
});

$('.messages').append(li);
```

Comment: `function(index, element) { ...}`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it was supposed be `$.map` :). The difference between the parameters of `$.each` and `$.map` can be confusing.

Comment: Yes, I always have to check the documentation, because they're not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

try for, the data has an array named results, from wich you have to select the first like following:

```
success: function(data) {
    var results = JSON.parse(data).results;
    results.forEach(function (result) {
    $('.messages').append("<li>" + data.results[0].text + "</li>");
  });
}
```